# How to remove Nothing Found To Display in Display Tag of Struts 1.3

Tags: struts, displaytag

I want to remove the message Nothing Found to Display in Struts 1.3 Display Tag , When no record fetch from database.

Its possible to do this...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my point of view the default behavior should be that no message must be displayed in case of empty data source.

The **empty_list** didn't work in my case. I tried this and it works:

```
<display:table ...
   <display:setProperty name="basic.msg.empty_list" value="" />

   <display:column ...
   ...
</display:table>
```

You can also customize you message in html format:

```
<display:setProperty name="basic.msg.empty_list" 
    value="<span style=\"font-size:12px\">No data</span>" />
```

I hope it will help...

Answer (score 2):

You can set a configuration property for the display table. [See here for more details](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/tagreference.html#display-el%3asetProperty).

The configuration property to set is `basic.msg.empty_list_row` which by default has the "Nothing found to display." value. [See this other page for more details](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/configuration.html).

So your code will look something like this:

```
<display:table ... >
   <display:setProperty name="basic.msg.empty_list_row"> 
      ... insert your choise here ... 
   </display:setProperty>
   ...
</display:table>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove "pagesize" attribute, it fixes the issue for struts2 & Displaytag 1.2 (that annoying message is called PageBanner"

Answer (score -2):

Add the following entry to `"displaytag.properties"` file and place the file in Class Path -

```
basic.msg.empty_list=
```

Also you can set any message here -

`basic.msg.empty_list=No` matching entries found !!!

Comment: this is not working. probably this will work: 
basic.msg.empty_list_row=